# Construction of measure on open and closed sets for $\epsilon>0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is from a book which supposed to help you prepare for entrance exam. I am currently on a chapter regarding construction of measure and Caratheodory theory. I am having quite a hard time understanding the information part, this is one of the exercises in the section.

Let $m$ be the Lebesgue measure and A a Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with $m(A)< \infty$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Show there exists $G$ open and $F$ closed such that $F\subset A\subset G$ and $m(G-F)<\epsilon$.

Comment: How are you defining a measurable set?

Comment: That's the regularity property of a measure, not sure whether there is a simple proof, but there is one on page 22 [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/measure_theory/measure_notes_ch2.pdf)